# How Can I get html table data from previous page in to current page using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've a table in (say, page1.html) html, I want to use this table's data in second page (say, page2.html).Is this possible? I'm beginner in php. please help!

Comment: Yes it probably is, you might want to look at how to dynamically load content into a web page via ajax. The rest depends on you setup which you gave us no information about

Answer (score 0):

Externalize this table in `table.html` and use `include "table.html";` in both pages, and don't forget to change your file extension `.html` to `.php`

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.include.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.require.php

**table.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**page1.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php include 'table.html'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php include 'table.html'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```